# Search if any string from a list of strings is in table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am getting from the client a list of strings (items he chose), and now I need to return results from the database. The client request is:

```
List<string> campaignStrings
```

List examples:

> [0] - "292 | Mac/June 17"
>
> [1] - "161 | Direct/June 17"

The way I am trying, without success, is:

```
var campaigns = ctx.V_CommercialCampaigns.Where(cam => campaignStrings.Any(x => cam.Name.Contains(x))).Select(id => id.Id).ToList();
```

I am using "Contains" because "Name" column might not be identical to the search terms.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem? Is there an error or invalid result?

Comment: No results at all @PiotrWojsa

Comment: Can you add examples of rows from V_CommercialCampaigns?

Comment: I guess your query will search records where name contains `292 | Mac/June 17` or `161 | Direct/June 17` are you sure you want to do that or you want to do a reverse of it?

Comment: What is `cam.Name`? Please provide some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether `cam.Name` occurs in `campaignStrings` list, then you need to change `where` clause to this:

```
.Where(cam => campaignStrings.Any(x => x.Contains(cam.Name)))
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this solution

```
var campaigns = ctx.V_CommercialCampaigns.Where(cam => campaignStrings.Contains((cam))).Select(id => id.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: "x does not exist in the current context". Did you mean "cam"?